# Wiremock withBodyFile OutOfMemoryError for large files

Tags: java, integration-testing, stub, wiremock

In the following stub request, I use `withBodyFile` which loads large files (`>300MB`) from specific locations on local disk using streams:

```
public void mockGetUrlContent(String url) {
    stubFor(get(urlEqualTo(url))
            .willReturn(ok()
                    .withBodyFile(FilenameUtils.getName(url))));
}
```

Once the stub is being called, wiremock tries to complete a served event and in order to log the response it uses the `from` [method](https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock/blob/23729a1049765d532682aa9c1b7031086436c594/src/main/java/com/github/tomakehurst/wiremock/http/LoggedResponse.java#L49) below:

```
  public static LoggedResponse from(Response response) {
    return new LoggedResponse(
        response.getStatus(),
        response.getHeaders() == null || response.getHeaders().all().isEmpty()
            ? null
            : response.getHeaders(),
        response.getBody(),
        response.getFault());
  }
```

When reached to wiremock's `Response` `getBody` [method](https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock/blob/6728eb79f440f561772421095d64ce3bda541fa9/src/main/java/com/github/tomakehurst/wiremock/http/Response.java#L123) it converts the stream in to `byte[]` and in that points it blows on `OutOfMemoryError` (Java heap space).:

```
  public byte[] getBody() {
    try (InputStream stream = bodyStreamSource == null ? null : getBodyStream()) {
      return stream == null ? null : ByteStreams.toByteArray(stream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
```

Any ideas about what am I doing wrong?

Your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: What you are doing wrong is trying to convert an input stream for a >300MB file into a `byte[]`. Solution: don't. Your `getBody()` method should return the `InputStream`.

Comment: man, I don't try to do it , its wiremock framework that does it, maybe its a bug in their framework or wrong configuration

Comment: Whoever is doing it, it's wrong.

Comment: This is hard-coded behaviour in WireMock at the moment unfortunately - it reads the entire response body into the request journal so that it's present for later verification, but with very large bodies like this that's not useful.

If you open a GH issue I'll work on adding a --truncate-large-response-bodies parameter or something similar so that you can limit the amount it keeps in memory.

Comment: @Tom I opened a GH issue following your request:
https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock/issues/1905

Comment: @Tom I added a workaround for this issue until fixed, see in the question's body

Comment: @Tom solved it and closed the issue.
https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock/commit/34761d64009534d951a24bd0aa4b152b93ead00c

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). I've rolled back the edit, feel free to add it as an answer though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WireMock 2.34.0 has a solution to this.

To ensure that logged response bodies are limited to a particular size you need to start WireMock with a new configuration parameter specifying the max size in bytes

When running standalone add the CLI parameter:

```
--logged-response-body-size-limit=1000000
```

When running in Java add the following to the configuration builder:

```
wireMockConfig().maxLoggedResponseSize(1000000)
```

Comment: first of all thank you for a quick fix. I've one question about the new behavior : what will happen if I have a file weigh about 300mb and I set the max logged response  to 20m max, will it trunct the rest 280m and the file body will be limited to 20m?

Comment: Yes, it'll still serve the whole body back to the client but it'll only capture the first 20m in the log.

Comment: Tom, again thank you for the quick address, i"ve just used your fix and works perfectly.